# change each option value javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to grab each `select` `option` value in a dropdown and use them to generate an image attribute for each option. For example, if the value of the `option` is `First Image` the `data-img-src` value will be the path to the image `folder/first-image.png`

The below code works fine but it generates the `data-img-src` for the first `option` only. What I need is to return the `data-img-src` for each option in the dropdown. How can I do this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){    
    $(".selector option").attr('data-img-src', function() {
        var file = this.value + '.png';
        var img = file.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
        var path = 'path to folder';
        return path + img    
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance and have a good day.

Comment: Supplying a function to the `attr()` method should mean that it iterates through all options. Can you provide an example of the problem, as your code should be working fine,

Comment: your code seems to work fine:: http://jsfiddle.net/8kypao9j/

Comment: each() was missing o iterate and update attribute of all options. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate and update attribute of all options.

```
$(".selector option").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-img-src', function() {
      var file = this.value + '.png';
      var img = file.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
      var path = 'path to folder';
      return path+img
    });
});
```

Comment: Working fine. Many thanks for your help. I will accept your reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `.each` to process each and every option in select dropdown

**JS Code :**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){    
   $(".selector option").each(function () {
     $(this).attr('data-img-src', function() {
     var file = this.value + '.png';
     var img = file.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
     var path = 'path to folder';
     return path+img});
     });
 });
```

**JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/6ttzm33r/**

Comment: As the above reply it's working fine, many thanks for your help.

Comment: happy to help, now can we close this question ?